# Nested lists and dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 3 different dictionaries in python like these

```
d1 = {'simple_key':'hello'}
d2 = {'k1':{'k2':'hello'}}
d3 = {'k1':[{'nest_key':['this is deep',['hello']]}]}
```

and I want to grab the word 'hello' from these dictionaries. 
But the problem I am facing is that I want to find a generic way to extract it. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't because their position is difference? You can create a function to do that, but in a single line I don't think it's possible.

Comment: What do you mean a "generic way to extract it"? Do you want a function/piece of code that tells your its 'location' (ie index in each nesting)

Comment: What do you mean by a "generic way"? In a sense, `dictionary[key1][key2]...[keyN]` is a generic way to get to any element. Or do you simply want to check that there is "hello" somewhere as a value?

Comment: `if "hello" in json.dumps(d1)`?

Comment: @Andrei exactly. I want to check that is the word 'hello' present in the values

Answer (score 3):

To get the key path in the dict using value, you could flatten it as json.

```
>>> from json_flatten import flatten
>>> d1 = {'simple_key':'hello'}
>>> d2 = {'k1':{'k2':'hello'}}
>>> d3 = {'k1':[{'nest_key':['this is deep',['hello']]}]}
>>> flatten(d2)
{'k1.k2': 'hello'}
>>> flat = flatten(d3)
{'k1.0.nest_key.0': 'this is deep', 'k1.0.nest_key.1.0': 'hello'}
```

To find the matching keys, use,

```
>>> [k for k, v in flat.items() if v == 'hello']
['k1.0.nest_key.1.0']
```

[JSON Flatten](https://pypi.org/project/json-flatten/)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep going inside the dictionary until you are at a value, not a dictionary. Recursion would be helpful here:

```
def get_value(dict):
     dict_value = list(dict.values())[0]
     if type(dict_value) is dict:
          get_value(dict_value)
     else: 
          return dict_value
```

there is probably a nicer way to do      `dict_value = list(dict.values())[0]` but not coming to mind right now

Comment: This looks like it would fail on his third example.

Comment: It wouldn't fail but it doesn't make it all the way through. I ran it and got  [{'nest_key': ['this is deep', ['hello']]}]

If the data structure isn't consistant then I'm not sure if there is way to go all the way down

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own flattener function which yields the values in a dict and members of a list:

```
def is_nonstring_iterable(x):
    return ((hasattr(x, "__iter__") or hasattr(x, "__getitem__")) 
        and not isinstance(x, str))

def flatten(thing):
    """ Recursively iterate through values in dictionary-like object or members 
        in lists, tuples or other non-string iterables """
    if hasattr(thing, "values"):
        thing = thing.values()
    if is_nonstring_iterable(thing):
        for element in thing:
            yield from flatten(element)
    else:
        yield thing

for d in [d1, d2, d3]:
    print(list(flatten(d)))
    print(any(item == "hello" for item in flatten(d))) # returns whether hello is found
```